# Node Beginner Book - requestHandlers

Tags: node.js, http

As the title says, I have a problem with what node.js command prompt says lies in the requestHandlers.js file. I am following the guide in the Node Beginner Book and until now, there have not been any problems with the book - or rather my code.

I have the following input:

index.js:

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");
var handle = {}
handle["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;
server.start(router.route, handle);
```

server.js:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
function start(route, handle) {
function onRequest(request, response) {
var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");
route(handle, pathname);
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server has started.");
}
exports.start = start;
```

router.js

```
function route(handle, pathname) {
console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function') {
handle[pathname]();
} else {
console.log("No request handler found for " + pathname);
}
}
exports.route = route;
```

requestHandlers.js

```
function start() {
console.log("Request handler "start" was called.");
}
function upload() {
console.log("Request handler "upload" was called.");
}
exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

And I have this output:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\requestHandlers.js:1
console.log("Request handler "start" was

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\index.js:1:153)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)"
```

I can't really see where the problem lies. I have followed the guide in the book and I have either copy-pasted the code from the book or written it myself. I have doublechecked the code for errors, but have not found any. I have remembered to use \'function\' for instance, so there would not be any mistakes in the code when entering it in node.js.

So any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: *"I can't really see where the problem lies"* - the code is hard to read, and that might explain why you can't see it. Others will likely have trouble too. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing the different string markers in JavaScript.

```
function start() {
   console.log("Request handler "start" was called.");
}
function upload() {
  console.log("Request handler "upload" was called.");
}
```

You can use " for the start and end of a string, but something like `"Request handler "start" was called."`

Is invalid, because you terminate the string at **"start** and start a new string at "**was called**.

If `start` and `upload` are variables just concatenate the strings with something like this:

```
"Request handler " + start + " was called."
```

or change your string to something like this:

```
"Request handler 'start' was called."
```

or remove the " around start and upload.

Comment: Thanks. Replacing "start" with start made it work. Though, as I tried to use 'start' instead, it would not work, even though I did use a backslash in front of both of the apostrophes both just before and after the word start. Like this \'start\', so as to cancel out these two apostrophes. Do you have any explanation...? Or should it work?

Comment: Could you post your current log statement? Is `start` a variable?